# Android Studio is not using the proper language

Tags: android-studio

Just trying to install Android Studio and I get hit with a language that I can't read. Not talking about coding languages.

[image: See what I'm talking about?]

I don't know how or why this is happening and I don't know how to change it. This may however be a Java issue but I'm unsure. Any ideas as to how and why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, what's your Os? Looks like windows 10 but what language package are you running?

Comment: I am using Quicksand over Segeo UI. After seeing your comment I changed everything back to default using regedit and it seems to be showing up fine now. Thanks man!

Comment: You welcome, those symbols looked more like font incompatibility rather than any other language that's why I asked.

Answer (score -2):

Java likes to use the default font of the system.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question you've posted? It's not clear.